# Problema ao acessar um arquivo acentuado (caractere combinante)

Tags: python, windows-xp, unicode, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou tentando fazer a listagem de uma pasta (arquivos, subpastas) em Python [2.7, no Windows XP], e estou tendo problemas com arquivos acentuados. Sei que o método [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) se comporta diferente caso o argumento seja uma string simples ou uma string unicode. Meu problema é que eu tenho arquivos codificados de maneiras diferentes:

```python
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('teste')
['a\xb4rvore.jpg']
>>> os.listdir(u'teste')
[u'a\u0301rvore.jpg']
>>> os.listdir('teste2')
['\xe1rvore.txt']
>>> os.listdir(u'teste2')
[u'\xe1rvore.txt']
```

No Windows Explorer, ambos os arquivos parecem normais: `árvore.jpg` e `árvore.txt`. Mas enquanto o segundo é listado normalmente, o primeiro dá uma mensagem de erro não importa como eu o acesse:

```python
def imprimir(pasta):
    print pasta
    for x in os.listdir(pasta):
        sub = os.path.join(pasta, x)
        if os.path.isfile(sub):
            print sub
        else:
            imprimir(sub)

>>> imprimir('teste2')
teste2
teste2\ßrvore.txt
>>> imprimir(u'teste2')
teste2
teste2\árvore.txt

>>> imprimir('teste')
teste
teste\a┤rvore.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "teste.py", line 11, in imprimir
    imprimir(sub)
  File "teste.py", line 6, in imprimir
    for x in os.listdir(pasta):
WindowsError: [Error 3] O sistema nÒo pode encontrar o caminho especificado: 'teste\\a\xb4rvore.jpg/*.*'
>>> imprimir(u'teste')
teste
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "teste.py", line 9, in imprimir
    print sub
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0301' in position 7: character maps to <undefined>
```

Como fazer para acessar esse outro arquivo? Não acho que ele esteja com o nome corrompido, pois `a\u0301` é uma [maneira válida](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm) de se produzir `á`. Entretanto, não sei como acessá-lo, e tenho um volume com vários arquivos nesse formato (posso evitar produzir arquivos semelhantes no futuro, mas ainda preciso processar os já existentes), acho impraticável convertê-los à mão.

Comment: Aparentemente isso é um bug na versão 2.7 da linguagem, já que o mesmo o código postado funciona perfeitamente com a versão 3.3.2 (que tenho instalado), modificando apenas a utilização da função `print`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com base [na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496/problema-ao-acessar-um-arquivo-acentuado-caractere-combinante/1508#1508) do @Luiz Vieira, e [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16467479/520779) no SO em inglês, consegui achar uma solução. O problema não estava no acesso ao arquivo em si, mas apenas ao imprimir seu nome na tela. O código abaixo, por exemplo, funciona normalmente:

```python
    if os.path.isfile(sub):
        with open(sub, 'rb') as f:
            with open(sub + u'.saida', 'wb') as s:
                s.write(f.read()) # Cria uma cópia perfeita do arquivo original
    ...
imprimir(u'teste') # Cuidado: somente a versão unicode funciona, a outra dá o mesmo erro
```

Porém, meu IDLE está utilizando a codificação `Cp850`, que aparentemente não consegue imprimir corretamente caracteres combinantes. A saída portanto é **normalizar** o nome do arquivo de modo que o par de caracteres seja representado por um único caractere pré-composto (`\u00e1`):

```python
def imprimir(pasta):
    print unicodedata.normalize('NFC', pasta)
    for x in os.listdir(pasta):
        sub = os.path.join(pasta, x)
        if os.path.isfile(sub):
            print unicodedata.normalize('NFC', sub)
        else:
            imprimir(sub)

>>> imprimir(u'teste')
teste
teste\árvore.jpg
>>> imprimir(u'teste2')
teste2
teste2\árvore.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Para mim parece ser apenas um problema de codificação na hora da impressão (chamada do método `print`) dos nomes de arquivos/pastas.

Tente utilizar a codificação com Unicode, alterando a sua fução imprimir da seguinte forma (note a adição de `.encode('utf8')` ao final das linhas com chamada para `print`):

```py
def imprimir(pasta):
    print pasta.encode('utf8')
    for x in os.listdir(pasta):
        sub = os.path.join(pasta, x)
        if os.path.isfile(sub):
            print sub.encode('utf8')
        else:
            imprimir(sub)
```

EDIT: Após reler a sua questão, acho que entendi outro ponto de dúvida. Você está usando o IDLE para testar interativamente, mas o IDLE usa outra codificação (no meu teste aqui eu havia criado um arquivo .py codificado em UTF-8, por isso não tive o mesmo problema). Para verificar a codificação do IDLE faça o seguinte:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp1252'
```

Assim, para exibir os nomes dos arquivos corretamente, você deve usar essa mesma codificação (ou alterar a codificação default no IDLE - o que eu sinceramente não sei como fazer). Fiz o teste aqui, e com a codificação cp1252 os nomes são corretamente exibidos:

```py
>>> def imprimir(pasta):
    print pasta.encode('cp1252')
    for x in os.listdir(pasta):
        sub = os.path.join(pasta, x)
        if os.path.isfile(sub):
            print sub.encode('cp1252')
        else:
            imprimir(sub)

>>> imprimir(u'teste')
teste
teste\árvore.jpg
>>> imprimir(u'teste2')
teste2
teste2\árvore.txt
>>>
```

Comment: Eu testei e está retornando o seguinte erro onde `path` é uma variável com o diretório: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#49>", line 1, in <module>
    imprimir(path)
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 8, in imprimir
    imprimir(sub)
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 2, in imprimir
    print pasta.encode('utf8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: A sua variável 'path' está codificada em Unicode? Por exemplo, ao invés de fazer path = 'teste' você fez path = u'teste'?

Comment: Funcionou agora, mas o arquivo `a┤rvore.txt` virou `aâ”¤rvore.txt`.

Comment: Como assim "virou"? Vc quer dizer que o conteúdo interno foi alterado ou a saída do console mostrou algo diferente de 'árvore.txt'?

Comment: @Zignd: Acho que entendi a sua dúvida. Editei a minha resposta pra tentar incluir essa possibilidade.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, não funcionou pra mim mas me deu a dica que eu precisava para achar uma solução. Postei em uma resposta separada.

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema semelhante com acentuação no python. Talvez isso resolva:

```python
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') # ou Latin1 ou cp1552
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, mas não funcionou pra mim. De acordo com a [documentação](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setdefaultencoding), esse método não está normalmente disponível para o programador usar: "Essa função só deve ser usada pela implementação do módulo `site` e, quando necessário, por `sitecustomize`. Uma vez usada pelo módulo `site`, ela é removida do *namespace* do módulo `sys`."